# How to order results with Postgres Full Text Search function using 2 tables with pg_trgm

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:

```
Table author
id (pk)  | first_name
1        | John
```

```
Table post
id (pk)  | author_id (fk) | content
1        | 1              | test content
```

I've created an extra table to hold the search results from the function:

```
Table post_search
author_id (fk) | post_id (fk) | created_at | content | first_name
```

I want to be able to provide a search term from front end and full text search on both tables, specifically `first_name` and `content`.

I have enabled `pg_trgm` on Postgresql:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
```

This is the Function:

```sql
CREATE
OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.search_posts(search text)
 RETURNS SETOF post_search 
LANGUAGE sql STABLE AS $ function $
SELECT
  P.author_id,
  P.id,
  P.created_at,
  P.content,
  A.first_name
FROM
  post P
  JOIN author A ON A.id = P.author_id
WHERE
  search <% concat_ws(' ', first_name, content)
ORDER BY
  similarity(search, concat_ws(' ', first_name, content))
LIMIT
  100;
$function$
```

The results from this function are not ordered by `first_name`, they're mixed, eg. the first result has the search keyword on the content and not on author's `first_name`. Is there a way to order the results by `first_name` and then by `content`?

Also, is it possible to have a function like this without the need of creating the extra `post_search` table? If so, can someone assist on the function code?

**Update:**

I've ended up using this function instead, I've added a `score` column and `order by` it.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_posts(search text)
    RETURNS SETOF post_search
    LANGUAGE sql
    STABLE
AS $function$
SELECT  P.author_id,P.id,P.created_at, P.content, A.first_name, ((similarity(search, P.content) + similarity(search, A.first_name)) / 2) as score
FROM post P
         JOIN profile A ON A.id = P.author_id
WHERE search % first_name or search % content
ORDER BY score desc
LIMIT 100;
$function$
```

Comment: `< %` is not a legal operator, so this doesn't work at all, nor is '$ function $' a legal string delimiter.  Also, you already have an ORDER BY.  Do you want to change it to so that it orders by something else?  Or what is it you want to do?  Do you want to order one way for purposes of the LIMIT, but then another way for presentation purposes?

Comment: @jjanes for some reason the Webstorm SQL plugin added spaces and I've just copy-pasted the function, sorry.  I've ended up adding a score column and now it works as intended. I'll update the question with my solution, I think it's working as it should.  I don't want to a-b sort by `first_name`, I just want to bring the results that match the `first_name` on top and then the content matches.

Comment: @jjanes I've updated the question to include another approach, I think it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Also, is it possible to have a function like this without the need of creating the extra post_search table?

One part of your question is well defined and easy to answer.  You could declare the function return an anonymous table with a specific structure:

```
....
RETURNS table  (author_id int, post_id int, created_at timestamptz, content text, first_name text)
```

Or you could declare a named composite type

```
create type post_search as (author_id int, post_id int, created_at timestamptz, content text, first_name text);
```

And then:

```
....
RETURNS setof post_search
```